# Upserting using Coda Pre-built Function in Pipedream

Tags: coda, pre-build-event, pipedream

I am using the variable path below to upsert a data to Coda.

```
{{steps.trigger.event.body.actions[0].name}}
```

The code above returns an example output below:

```
CO-DEN - IBC 2021
```

What I really want to insert is only ‘CO-DEN’, the first word from the output. Is there anyway to tokenize the data to be upserted? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I can help with the easy & ugly solution. Simply use the *split function* to achieve what you want.

In example:

```
var sentence = '{{steps.trigger.event.body.actions[0].name}}';
var firstWord = sentence.split(' ')[0];
```